# System sounds always play from built-in speakers in lock screen

Tags: sound, lock-screen

I am on Ubuntu 20.04.

Since recently, there are loud system sounds when locked/logged out.

For example, when locking (through the top right menu -> lock), a lock system sound plays from the built in speakers. A sound also plays when plugging in or out the charger.

These sounds only happen in lock screen, and never while logged in.
These sounds always play at maximum volume, and the media keys do not seem to have any effect while in lock screen.
These sounds play from the computer speakers (Speakers - Built-in Audio), regardless of whether the headphone jack is plugged in or if any other audio device is available.

OS Name: Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS
OS Type 64-bit
GNOME Version 3.36.3
Windowing System X11

Answer (score 0):

First run

```
echo autospawn = no >> ~/.config/pulse/client.conf  #use ~/.pulse/client.conf on Ubuntu <= 12.10

killall pulseaudio

LANG=C pulseaudio -vvvv --log-time=1 > ~/pulseverbose.log 2>&1
```

Then Use `pacmd` and `rm -r ~/.pulse*; pulseaudio -k`

Try to test it out by running

pastebin.com/3nhedfx6

pastebin.com/4UVxCJXM

pastebin.com/XxbSDvRR